# Datatables infinite scroll without server-side pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a datatable which is using ajax. I wanted infinite scroll pagination. The only way I could figure out how to do it was to enable `serverSide` processing/pagination. This is now presenting a problem because I want browser-side search and sorting. So how can I have infinite scroll browser-side (No `serverSide`)?

Note: bootstrap & jquery are also loaded.

```
$(() => {
    let user_level = 0
    getObject('user_data').then(user => {
        user_level = user.user_level
    })
    let adjusted = false
    getItem('access_token').then(storage => {
        let access_token = storage.value
        inventory_table = $('#inventory_table').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
                let payload = {
                    start: data.start,
                    len: data.length,
                    end: data.start + data.length
                }
                $.ajax( "https://myapi/list_inventory", {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {   //Include the bearer token in header
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${access_token}`);
                    }
                }).done(resp => {
                    callback({
                        draw: data.draw,
                        data: resp,
                        /*recordsTotal: 300,
                        recordsFiltered: 300*/
                    })
                    inventory_table.responsive.recalc()
                    inventory_table.fixedHeader.adjust()
                    if(!adjusted){
                        inventory_table.columns.adjust().draw()
                        adjusted = true
                    }
                }).fail(resp => {
                    console.log('err', resp.responseJSON)
                })

            },
            rowReorder: {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
            },
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: 'column',
                    target: 'tr'
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'photo',
                    title: '',
                    data: 'photo',
                    defaultContent: '',
                    className: "text-center",
                    'render': data => {
                        return `<img src="https://myapi/${data}" height="70" />`;
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'item_name',
                    title: 'Item',
                    data: 'item_name',
                    className: "text-left"
                },
                {
                    name: 'quant',
                    title: 'Qty',
                    data: 'quant',
                    className: "text-center",
                    render: (quant, type, row, meta) => {
                        let this_id = `quant_${meta.row}`
                        if(user_level >= 8){
                            $(`#${this_id}`).editable('https://myapi/do_edit_quant', {
                                type : "number",
                                select : true,
                                width : 30,
                                onblur: 'submit',
                                method: 'POST',
                                name: 'quant',
                                submitdata: {
                                    item_id: row['id']
                                },
                                ajaxoptions: {
                                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {   //Include the bearer token in header
                                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${access_token}`);
                                    }
                                },
                                intercept: (res) => {
                                    res = JSON.parse(res)
                                    return res.new_quant
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        let color = 'black'
                        let font_weight = 'normal'
                        if(quant <= row.alert_thresh){
                            color = 'red'
                            font_weight = 'bold'
                        }
                        return `<span id="${this_id}" style="color: ${color}; font-weight: ${font_weight}">${quant}</span>`
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'alert_thresh',
                    title: 'Min',
                    data: 'alert_thresh',
                    className: "text-center",
                    render: (alert_thresh, type, row, meta) => {
                        let this_id = `alert_thresh_${meta.row}`

                        $(`#${this_id}`).editable('https://myapi/do_edit_thresh', {
                            type : "number",
                            select : true,
                            width : 30,
                            onblur: 'submit',
                            method: 'POST',
                            name: 'alert_thresh',
                            submitdata: {
                                item_id: row['id']
                            },
                            ajaxoptions: {
                                beforeSend: (xhr) => {   //Include the bearer token in header
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${access_token}`)
                                }
                            },
                            intercept: (res) => {
                                res = JSON.parse(res)
                                return res.alert_thresh
                            }
                        })

                        return `<span id="${this_id}">${alert_thresh}</span>`
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'location',
                    title: 'Loc',
                    data: 'section',
                    className: "text-center",
                    render: (section, type, row, meta) => {
                        return `${section} - ${row.location}`
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'distributor',
                    title: "Distributor",
                    data: 'dist_name',
                    className: "text-center",
                    defaultContent: 'None',
                    render: (distributor, type, row, meta) => {
                        return `${distributor}`
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'last_user',
                    title: 'Last User',
                    data: 'last_user_id',
                    className: "text-center",
                    defaultContent: 'None',
                    render: (last_id, type, row, meta) => {
                        return last_id !== undefined && last_id !== null ? `${row.first_name} ${row.last_initial}.` : 'None'
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'updated',
                    title: "Updated",
                    data: 'last_update_date',
                    className: "text-center",
                    defaultContent: 'None'
                },
                {
                    name: 'actions',
                    title: '',
                    className: "text-center",
                    render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
                        let output = ''
                        output += `<a class="btn btn-warning check_btn" onclick="deduct_qty(${row.id})" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg">&nbsp;1</i>
                                    </a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="new_order.html?item_id=${row.id}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg">&nbsp;Order More</i>
                                    </a>
                                    `
                        return output
                    }
                }
            ],
            asStripeClasses: [],
            scrollY: '100vh',
            deferRender: true,
            scrollCollapse: false,
            scroller: {
                loadingIndicator: true
            },
            language: {
                search: "",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search"
            },
            initComplete: () => {
                $('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('form-control form-control-lg')
            },
            info: false
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I have never used it (hence this comment, and not an answer), but maybe [this scroller extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/)? There is a [client-side demo here](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html). It claims to be [compatible](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) with Bootstrap-4.

Comment: That's what I'm using. You can see in the code. I'll try again. I forget why I had to use server rendering to begin with.

Comment: OK - sorry - I completely missed that (obviously).